# Serialize json object with date - javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, datetime, extjs

How to serialize json object with specific date format ?

json object

```
{"date": "/Date(-62135596800000)/"}
```

to string

```
{"date": "Jan 01,1"}
```

and i am using extjs as a core library

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code is not finished, but it should give you what you need to achieve your goal. If not, let me know :)

```
function rxFn(str,m1) { 
    var d = new Date(parseInt(m1,10));
    return <whatever format you wish based on the date object>
}

function fixDateFormat(jsonObject) {
    for(var i in jsonObject) {
        switch(typeof jsonObject[i]) {
            case 'object':
                fixDateFormat(jsonObject);
                break;
            case 'string':
                jsonObject[i].replace(/Date\(([0-9]+)\)/,rxFn);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to loop over the json object recursivly and fix all the date serializations you find.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin for your answer
As i am using Extjs library so i have [modify the code](http://techneerajnandwana.blogspot.com/2011/10/javascript-serialize-json-object-to.html) and work perfectly